# Show f is uniformly continuous iff inf D(epsilon, a) > 0

Tags: real-analysis

For a function $f : A \rightarrow  R$, $a\in A$, and $\varepsilon>0$ given, let

$D(\varepsilon,a)=sup\{\delta:|x-a|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|< \varepsilon\}$

Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $\;\inf _{a \in A} \; D(\epsilon,a) > 0 $

I know that f is uniformly continuous if $f : [a,b] \rightarrow R$ is continuous, and that $f$ is continuous at a iff $D(\varepsilon,a) > 0 \quad \forall > 0$.

Comment: You should follow the easy directions of this site to write mathematics, in particular after 4 months in and several questions asked. It's very hard to understand you.

Comment: I don't think you have the the definition of uniform continuity correct.

Comment: The definition I'm using is that f is uniformly continuous if f is continuous at the point a for every point a in A. I listed a theorem in my question though that I thought might be helpful.